# Using "could" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering what **could** means such a given sentence:

> you **could** use "help" in your sentence.

I mean that "could" is used in the past situations but i only consider this sentence and its exact meaning.

Let me explain what I comprehend according to this sentence:

> you did not use "help" in your sentence. However, there is another verb which is "help" that you can depict your idea with the same cleanness.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/could

could (vb)

1. used as an auxiliary to indicate **`suggestion of a course of action`**: you could take the car tomorrow if it's raining.

Answer (score 1):

You have could (past indicative) and could* (past subjunctive). The asterik marks the subjunctive form. 
could* does not refer to the past but - despite its name "past" - it refers to the present and
expresses the idea of possibility.
Could* you help me? - This means: Would it be possible that you help me?

I don't know what you mother-tongue is. If it has subjunctive forms you should* understand could*. If your mother-tongue has no subjunctive forms then it's a bit difficult to get the idea of subjunctive.